# How to retrieve full docstring as String in python? (content when you call help())

Tags: python, string, inspect

I know you could do `something.__doc___` or even `inspect.getdoc(something)`. However I want to retrieve the full help() display as a String. In other words, the entire thing when you do `help(something)`. Notice how `inspect.getdoc(inspect)` retrieves a fraction of content on display than when you do `help(inspect)` in interpreter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am relatively sure it is not possible. I believe the best thing you could do is try to replicate the help() output using `__name__` and `__doc__`.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this guide](https://www.journaldev.com/22892/python-help-function), defining the docstrings should make it available to the `help()` function. I have tested this myself and it does work.

The format for the docstring I use, which the guide also happens to use, is as follows:

```
"""
This is a description of the function
:param name_of_param: what the parameter is for
:return: what the function returns
"""
```

Comment: Well yea, but I wonder how to store the contents of help() as string value

Comment: @Snusifer from [this document](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/help): "The help() method is used for interactive use. It's recommended to try it in your interpreter when you need help to write Python program and use Python modules." You shouldn't need to get the result as a string.